# How to join tables and queries in C# with access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

this is how i join 2 tables and select form it:

```
OleDbDataAdapter DataA = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"Select tfr.FeedID, tf.FeedName, tfr.FeedQuantity, tf.DM
                                                        FROM tFeeds AS tf
                                                        INNER JOIN tFeedsRations AS tfr ON (tf.FeedID=tfr.FeedID)", Connection);
```

but what about adding a access query to this select command?
for example I want to add this statement to my select command:

```
Select qfq.FeedDMQuantites
From qFeeds_Quantities as qfq
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well add another `JOIN` condition to this table `qFeeds_Quantities` (assuming you have a relationship to this table or a common column among other table).

Assuming you have a common column like `FeedID` in this new table as well you can make another `JOIN` like

```
select tfr.FeedID, tf.FeedName, tfr.FeedQuantity, 
tf.DM, qfq.FeedDMQuantites
FROM (tFeeds AS tf
INNER JOIN tFeedsRations AS tfr ON tf.FeedID = tfr.FeedID)
INNER JOIN qFeeds_Quantities as qfq ON tf.FeedID = qfq.FeedID;
```

If you want to include another `JOIN` then parenthesize like

```
FROM ((tFeeds AS tf
INNER JOIN tFeedsRations AS tfr ON tf.FeedID = tfr.FeedID)
INNER JOIN qFeeds_Quantities as qfq ON tf.FeedID = qfq.FeedID)
INNER JOIN BLAH AS bll ON bll.test = tf.test;
```

Comment: tanks but this is what i've qot:
Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(tf.FeedID=tfr.FeedID)

Comment: ( cc: @SaraniO ) The Access Database Engine is going to want parentheses around one of those INNER JOINs, e.g., `... FROM (foo INNER JOIN bar ON ...) INNER JOIN baz ON ...`. It's "an Access thing".

Comment: @GordThompson tanks, would you please show it on my code?
because I add parantheses around one of them and it gives me  Syntax error in FROM clause.

Comment: @Rahul Tanks a lot, it worked,
Now what about if I want to add another join condition to this?
what should I do?

Comment: @SaraniO, increase the parenthesis like *see edit ...*